# Java Stream: Comparing if one list is equal to START of second list (not comparing whole list)

Tags: java, java-stream

I have got two lists in Java for example `list1 = (A,B,C)`, `list2 = (A,B,C,D)` I want these list to be compared as equal since list1 is equal to the START of list2.

I have got this code without streams:

```
List<LetterForAnalysis> textList = LetterHelper
        .findNikudLetterForAnalysisList(text);

List<LetterForAnalysis> expressionList = LetterHelper
        .findNikudLetterForAnalysisList(expression.getHebrew());

if (textList.size() > expressionList.size()) {
    return false;
}
for (int i = 0; i < textList.size(); i++) {
    if (!LetterForAnalysis.isEqual(textList.get(i),
            expressionList.get(i))) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Is is possible to do this with Java streams? And if so, how? I am trying to learn how to use streams and it is really difficult. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `return textList.equals(expressionList.subList(0, textList.size());` or similar: might be off by one there. No need for loops or streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an IntStream to stream over the indices of list A and `allMatch` to check if a condition is true for every index. This will short circuit if a predicate returns false early in the stream.

```java
if (a.size() > b.size()) {
    return false;
}
final IntStream indices = IntStream.range(0, a.size());
return indices.allMatch((i) -> a.get(i).equals(b.get(i)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try it like this:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1","2", "3", "4"));
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));

boolean result = Collections.indexOfSubList(list1, list2) == 0;
```

`Collections.indexOfSubList(list1, list2)` will return an index, where sublist begins.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think streams would be an appropriate solution to your problem. Streams are meant to be terminated, and you would want to terminate your stream as soon as you find a mismatch of characters.

Please note that the solution you posted has a bug as your for loop variables is initialized to 1, not 0.

```
public boolean startsWith(List<LetterForAnalysis> needles, List<LetterForAnalysis> haystack) {
    if (needles.size() > haystack.size())
      return false;
    Iterator<LetterForAnalysis> needlesIter = needles.iterator();
    Iterator<LetterForAnalysis> haystackIter = haystack.iterator();
    while (needlesIter.hasNext()) {
      if (!haystackIter.hasNext() 
          || !LetterForAnalysis.isEqual(hayStackIter.next(), needlesIter.next())
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint to the bug.